# Programatically convert file to PDF with printer driver from Java

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation

I'd like to be able to convert any printable file to PDF.  This is very easy to do with a printer driver.  Is it possible to do it programmatically from Java?

Comment: I need to be able to do this on both Windows and Linux.  Aspose and IText, are, I believe, paid only.  Is there are free solution?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use system calls ? If you can, exec() system call with pandoc can solve your problem. See [this answer.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71400)

I am not aware of Java libraries that can do this.

Comment: That might work, if Pandoc works on both Windows and Linux.  I'll take a look.  thanks